# What would be the way to implement a game on Stellar?

Tags: transactions

I'm curious how would it be possible to implement a game similar to one mentioned [here](https://hackernoon.com/ethereum-development-walkthrough-part-1-smart-contracts-b3979e6e573e). The rules are trivial (and sort of dumb):

> In our little game, in each round, the wrestlers will be able to put
>   in a sum of money, and if one put in double the money of the other(in
>   total), he will win.

But while the implementation in Solidity looks straight forward, I can't see a way to implement a similar logic on Stellar.

What could be a possible approach?

Answer (score 1):

How about using one extra account "Dealer", just like playing poker games?

step 1

- wrestler A -> Dealer
- wrestler B -> Dealer

step 2

- Dealer decides who wins (if there's a winner)

step 3

- Dealer pays the winner (or refund them if no winner?)

You will need a simple code to monitor and compare the amounts sent to Dealer at step 1. Logic is simple, at the cost of a small extra transaction fee.

Comment: In that case, Dealer is some app running somewhere.  The Dealer could cheat, bend the rules, or just die.  So not really the same have having this logic in a smart contract that is independent and decentralized.

Comment: That could be an issue... and then we might need another blockchain to mount this logic check...